# How to retrieve Post from one Category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have problem in wordpress.
I want to take post from only one category.
For Example: I have 3 category name is 'a','b'and'c'.I want to show in my index page only 'a' category.Don't want to show other category's post.
How can I solve???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <?php
         global $post;
         $args = array(
                        'numberposts' => 5,
                        'orderby' => 'post_date',
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'category' => 27 //this is the ID for your category
          );
         $myposts = get_posts($args);
         foreach ($myposts as $post) {
         setup_postdata($post);?>
            <!--post loop -->
               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    <?php }; ?>
```

Your array sets up the parameters of the display of posts. With this, it's pulling from one category (based on ID). If you wanted, you could go by name with `'category_name' => 'a'`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `pre_get_posts`.... which allows you to modify the query *before* it is run, which is obviously more efficient than running a new query on the blog page.

Adapted from the [codex example for `pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_categories_on_your_main_page)

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'so_single_cat_only_in_index' );
function so_single_cat_only_in_index( $query ){
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'category_name', 'a' );
    }
}
```